# Numericupdowns have different behaviours

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three different numericupdowns in my C# project, which all of three have the same properties and same values:

[image: NumericUpDown2]

[image: NumericUpDown3]

[image]

All of three have the same method linked up, which is numericUpDown1_ValueChanged:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            applyAnimationTimeout();
        }
```

All of three have their values changed at startup via the CheckAnimationTimeout method.

```
private void checkAnimationTimeout()
        {
            numericUpDown1.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.animationResizeTop; // resize timing
            numericUpDown2.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.animationDockBottom; // resize timing
            numericUpDown3.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.animationSettingResize;//animationSettingResize; // resize setting timing
        }
```

All of three have their value, and therefore their related setting, modified via the applyAnimationTimeout() method.

```
private void applyAnimationTimeout()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.animationResizeTop = (int)numericUpDown1.Value; // assign value to the correct NumericUpDown
           Properties.Settings.Default.animationDockBottom = (int)numericUpDown2.Value; // assign value to the correct NumericUpDown
            Properties.Settings.Default.animationSettingResize = (int)numericUpDown3.Value; // assign value to the correct NumericUpDown
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        }
```

All of three have their properties specified with the exact same type and exact same scope.
[image]

Yet, the only one which value gets correctly changed is numericUpDown1. The only times these properties are modified are inside these methods, and the only time the checkAnimationTimeout method is called is at startup of the form, inside check().
[image]

If I do forcefully run checkAnimationTimeout and applyAnimationTimeout at runtime, it does work until I close the form. But when I re-open it, it resets the values of only these two numeric up downs to their minimum, as if the value I've inserted isn't correct. There isn't any other method which modifies these properties.

I've tried re-adding these numeric up downs, setting their value forcefully based on a label in the form even, rewriting the code multiple times, copying numericUpDown1, but nothing - always the same problem, always with the same two properties and always with the same two controls. Because if I were to set those to load the first property, it'd work. I have no idea what is causing it or what can I even do to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `numericUpDown1` value at startup from settings - it triggers your `numericUpDown1_ValueChanged` handler. Triggers **before** `numericUpDown2` and `numericUpDown3` receive their values from settings.

As it happens on startup, `numericUpDown2` and `numericUpDown3` are set with their default (minimum) values. And so, `ValueChanged` handler captures its defaults and **overwrite to settings** (mark this moment, see below solution).

Call chain looks like:

`Settings read -> numericUpDown1 -> ValueChanged handler -> Settings write -> Settings save -> Settings read -> numericUpDown2 -> ...`

Not:

`Settings read -> numericUpDown1 -> Settings read -> numericUpDown2 -> Settings read -> numericUpDown3`

as you may expect.

---

Overall trouble is that you're forcing settings rewrite and save every time one of `numericUpDown` changes.

I suggest moving your code from `applyAnimationTimeout()`, or its call from the `ValueChanged` handler to, for example, the `FormClosing` handler. This way, the settings won't be overwritten every time the `numericUpDown` values change, but only once, when you close your form.
Of course, the settings will be correctly restored.

Code example:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ...

        this.FormClosing += delegate
        {
            // Capture values and save only once before form closed
            applyAnimationTimeout();
        };
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Comment or remove its call away from here
        // applyAnimationTimeout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - after reading your explanation, it was a rather easy fix. Thanks a lot anyway!